GraalVMでネイティブコード化したjavaアプリをJVMなしのPCで実行する方法
ファイルをserverにuploadするjavaアプリを開発しています。
GraalVMでをネイティブコード化し、JVMなしのWindowsPC上で実行したいです。
実行方法はどうなりますか？exeファイルとして生成して実行するやり方などあれば教えて下さい。シンプルで簡単なものがいいです。
